# What does "Guinea" mean in names of countries?

Tags: word-choice

Why are there so many countries with the name "Guinea"?  Like Papua New Guinea, Equatorial Guinea, Guinea Bissau, Guinea, etc?

Comment: *Guinea* refers to a large area of west Africa, taking its name from the name of the people who live there. (The name's etymology is uncertain.) So smaller sections need to differentiate themselves from the whole.

Comment: And "New" prefixing a name suggests a location which is somehow considered to be a clone or colony of the named location, even though it's physically distinct and often a great distance away,  Eg, "New York" refers to York England.

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits a history or geography site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

This is question not really confined to English, and is probably better suited for History Stack Exchange. In any case, it can be answered by a small tour through Wikipedia.

From a European point of view, the African countries were discovered first; among them is the [Republic of Guinea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guinea):

> The English term Guinea comes directly from the Portuguese word **Guiné**, which emerged in the mid-15th century to refer to the lands inhabited by the Guineus, a generic term for the black African peoples below the Senegal River, as opposed to the 'tawny' Zenaga Berbers, above it, whom they called Azenegues or Moors.

This also covers Guinea-Bissau and Equatorial Guinea, which have a slightly different name to distinguish them from the republic.

As for [Papua New Guinea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Guinea), which was discovered later:

> When the Portuguese and Spanish explorers arrived in the island via the Spice Islands, they also referred to the island as Papua. However, the name New Guinea would later be used by Westerners starting with the Spanish explorer Yñigo Ortiz de Retez in 1545, referring to the similarities of the indigenous people's appearance with the natives of the Guinea region of Africa.

Comment: There is a similar story with the Guineas' coastal counterparts in South America, the *Guianas* (though the names are independently derived from Arawak or Carib, and apparently unrelated).